# Lubuntu kernel dev - sched_setaffinity is not defined

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write a *kernel* module which uses `sched_setaffinity()`. It's declared in `linux/sched.h` but implemented in `core.c` (afaik), now the problem is it seems my system does not have `core.c` anywhere so the linking fails (`sched_setaffinity` undefined). I've been trying to google around but made no progress.. I have the `linux-kernel-source` package installed, is there something like `kernel-devel` (as in redhat distros) I should be aware of? What would be a fix for this? I also tried downloading a full kernel source and copy those missing files to the kernel source dir in `/usr/src/`, but didn't work out well..

Thanks!

I'm using a lubuntu system, kernel is of version 3.5.0-21-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the package `linux-headers-generic`. This installs the kernel headers and creates the symlink /lib/modules/version/build that many kernel modules (and kernel module building tutorials) expect to be there.